# how to recognize text in images of JPEG, PNG,etc formate using php

Tags: php

is this possible to detect or recognize and print the letter using php functions ,but some website are recognize and prints the text (Max accuracy) how it works ? there is any other ways available to do this

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are looking for OCR (optical character recognition) software.
a quick google search turned up http://phpocr.sourceforge.net/ .